# pyspark: how to improve python type hints for DataFrames?

Tags: pyspark, type-hinting

I'm using vscode with help of dbx to run pyspark code in Databricks cluster. Even though I'm using github copilot, code completion and navigation is rather poor due the lack of type hints. I thought of having dataclasses for each DataFrame and annotate them everywhere.